# Array but with 16 digits

Tags: java

Now I know that just putting an array with 16 digits is too much for arrays and it will give an answer but for a cybersecurity class I wish to gain access to routers around my neighborhood.

I won't mess with them but I serve to prove a point and all the routers are the same thanks to living in the middle of nowhere. They are 16 digits long.

So can anyone help me solve how I would get 16 digits together and create it all in a txt file?

What I want to do is create a new file, and then make things that would make it so that it is a dictionary-type in that it has every number of 0000000000000000 -> 9999999999999999.

The creating of the file is no problem for me, but how would I create this dictionary of numbers with a 16 number sequence?

Edit: I thought about splitting it up into 4 4 digit things but I am unsure how I would make sure that they are a) not the same number as before and b), make a space after the sixteenth digit is in.

Comment: with a big for() loop. you can do it!

Comment: I was hoping there might be an easier way to do it...

Comment: well, one that doesn't have 5000 lines in it.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what you are actually trying to do. Try to reword your question so it is more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your number (99...9) has 16 digits. In term of data type in Java, it about 53 bit (<64 bit so far) so it is an `long`

But, assume that each number is 64 bit.
So the file size could be size = (99..99) (number) * 64 (bit per number) = **73k Tera Byte (impossible to store in a text file in *normal way*!)**

**So you should consider another way (?)**

<strike>Furthermore, you can not declare `long l = 999999999999999`; because the compiler got the error (integer number to large), but this works: `long l = Long.parseLong("9999999999999999");`</strike>

Hope this can help you !

---

**Edit:** Declare by `long l = 9999999999999999999l;` (`l` can be both upper and lower case, thanks @Tom)

Comment: Or you could replace the string parsing with long l =  9999999999999999l; so the compiler would know it's not an int you're trying to create

Comment: In addition to the size of the file, mention how long it would take to create it. **If** 10^9 numbers per second were added to the file, it'd take a bit less than four months. More realistic is a rate of 10^7-10^8 numbers per second.

Comment: @DanielFischer: i don't mention it because i don't know what does this question asking for. Seriously, if he mention about create such a big dictionary like this, is he/she talking about dictionary-attack?

Comment: Well, I have no idea what the OP wants to do either. But it seems the enormity of the task has not been recognised, so I think emphasising it is good.

Comment: Ok thanks to y'all I'll be including it here. 
But yea, I didn't realize it would take that much time so thanks everyone!

Comment: @BachT: I recommend using an uppercase `L` at the end, because `l` might get confused with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you want to do this:

```
for(Double i = 0; i < 10000000000000000;i++)  
{  
       String s = i.toString();
       bufferedWriter.write(s);
}
```

Which will write the String representation of the current `Double` to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

The question could be clearer, but if I understand you'd like to have a field like this:

```
int i = 10000000000000000;
```

or maybe

```
int[] i = { 1000000000000000 };
```

but that overflows an integer.  Java has something called a BigInteger class which can hold arbitrarily large numbers, but you initialize them with strings:

```
List<BigInteger> i = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
i.add(new BigInteger("1000000000000000"));
```

The downside is you can't use normal arithmetic operands on it, like bi1 + bi2, but the BigInteger class gives you pretty much all you need to work with them as if they were regular numbers.  [Here's the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to do this would be with a `for` loop.  A `LinkedList` would be best for the sake of speed.

```
LinkedList<Double> list = new LinkedList<Double>();
for(double i=0;i<10000000000000000;i++)
    list.add(i);
//Output list to file next.
```

Comment: This won't work in any case, list is int indexed.

Comment: also, I believe the number is too big...
That;s what it was saying on NetBeans...

Comment: Ah.  In that case, you should be more descriptive with your questions.  I don't appreciate -4 for trying.  Edit your question to be more descriptive, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I never downvoted you. I can't :(